# Is it possible to modify a specific field on a Kubernetes manifest on-the-fly?

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to modify a live Kubernetes manifest, on-the-fly and non-interactively? I know `kubectl edit` allows for this behavior, but this requires user interaction in an editor that is opened when the command is invoked. I need to be able to do this without user interaction (for example in a script, etc.). Is this possible with a simple command - perhaps a variation of `kubectl edit`?

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is `kubectl patch` ([docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/)).

For example, Given a deployment you can for example update the `.spec.template.spec.containers[].image` field using the following command:

```bash
kubectl patch deployment my-deploy \
  --patch '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": {"containers": [{"image": "nginx:1.12.5"}]}}}}'
```

This way, you only specify the fields of the object that have changed. You may also pass a file with the changed fields instead of inline json, eg:

```bash
cat ./patch.yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: nginx:1.12.5

kubectl patch deployment my-deploy --patch-file ./patch.yaml
```

Both versions support `json` and `yaml` to specify the changeset.

Answer (score 0):

The whole Kubernetes is built around APIs. You can e.g. use any http client to interact with the [REST API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) directly, if you want.

You can also create or modify Kubernetes manifest files in plain Yaml text files, and *apply* them using the `kubectl` CLI or any http client.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I'm looking for a way to add `.spec.ttlSecondsAfterFinished` field to a Job, created from CronJob on-the-fly with no interaction. As for now I'm up to this way to perform it:

```
kubectl create job --from=cronjob/cron-job-name job-name -o yaml --dry-run=client | yaml fields modifier (like yq) | kubectl apply -f -
```

Here is [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) util link

Maybe it's something that fits your use-case.

Searching for something more natural like setting new fields with `--set` haven't led me to any result at the moment. Investigating `kubectl patch`

**Update**

Found it !!!

You should use it like this: create your object and output its' json, then patch it!

```
kubectl create job --from=cronjob/cron-job-name job-name -o json | kubectl patch -f - -p='{"spec":{"ttlSecondsAfterFinished": 10}}'
```